# UI not being updated after state change

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am stuck in a weird situation. Have cross-checked all the reference. Problem is my timer is not updating the modelBottomSheet.
This is my WorkOutTracker

```
    class WorkOutTracker extends StatefulWidget {
  const WorkOutTracker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WorkOutTracker> createState() => _WorkOutTrackerState();
}

class _WorkOutTrackerState extends State<WorkOutTracker> {
  final WorkoutBloc workoutBloc = WorkoutBloc();
  String elapsedTime = "0s";
  late Timer timer;

  void updateElapsedTime(Timer timer) {
    workoutBloc.add(StartWorkout(timer: timer));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: BlocConsumer<WorkoutBloc, WorkoutState>(
        bloc: workoutBloc,
        listenWhen: (previous, current) => current is WorkoutActionState,
        buildWhen: (previous, current) => current is! WorkoutActionState,
        listener: (context, state) {
          // TODO: implement listener
          print("sdsd");
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        _buildStartWorkoutButton(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                if (state is Workingout) _buildResumeCancelButtons(),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildStartWorkoutButton() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              'Start workout',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: const Text(
              'Start with new routine',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            onPressed: () => _onStartWorkoutButtonPressed(context),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildResumeCancelButtons() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: const Text(
              'Resume workout',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            onPressed: () => _onResumeWorkoutButtonPressed(context),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: const Text(
              'Cancel workout',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            onPressed: () => _onCancelWorkoutButtonPressed(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onStartWorkoutButtonPressed(BuildContext context) {
    timer = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      (Timer t) {
        updateElapsedTime(t);
      },
    );
    showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return ExcerciseTracker();
      },
    );
  }

  void _onResumeWorkoutButtonPressed(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return ExcerciseTracker();
      },
    );
  }

  void _onCancelWorkoutButtonPressed() {
    timer.cancel();
    workoutBloc.add(EndWorkout());
  }
}
```

Please focus on _onStartWorkoutButtonPressed, here i am starting a timer and showing a modalBottomSheet.

Next file is WorkoutBloc

```
class WorkoutBloc extends Bloc<WorkoutEvent, WorkoutState> {
  WorkoutBloc() : super(WorkoutInitial()) {
    on<StartWorkout>(startWorkout);
    on<EndWorkout>(endWorkout);
    on<ResumeWorkout>(resumeWorkout);
  }

  FutureOr<void> startWorkout(
      StartWorkout event, Emitter<WorkoutState> emit) async {
    //starting workout
    try {
      print(event.timer.tick);
      return emit(Workingout(second: event.timer.tick));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(Error());
    }
  }

  FutureOr<void> endWorkout(
      EndWorkout event, Emitter<WorkoutState> emit) async {
    try {
      return emit(EndWorkingout());
    } catch (e) {
      emit(Error());
    }
  }

  FutureOr<void> resumeWorkout(
      ResumeWorkout event, Emitter<WorkoutState> emit) {}
}
```

This file is yiedling the Workingout state, on every second change. I have verified it by print statement, and its working fine.

And lastFile

```
class ExcerciseTracker extends StatefulWidget {
  
  const ExcerciseTracker({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExcerciseTracker> createState() => _ExcerciseTrackerState();
}

class _ExcerciseTrackerState extends State<ExcerciseTracker> {
  final WorkoutBloc workoutBloc = WorkoutBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85,
      child: BlocConsumer<WorkoutBloc, WorkoutState>(
        bloc: workoutBloc,
        listenWhen: (previous, current) => current is WorkoutActionState,
        buildWhen: (previous, current) => current is! WorkoutActionState,
        listener: (context, state) {
          // TODO: implement listener
          print("sdsd");
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          print("BlocConsumer rebuilt with state: $state");
          return Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    // Taken from here https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/1.0/emoji-data.txt
                    const Text(
                      '\u{1F525} 234 ',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      _getFormattedElapsedTime(state).toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.close,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 30.0,
                        semanticLabel:
                            'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  String _getFormattedElapsedTime(WorkoutState state) {
    // Calculate elapsed time using the timer
    print(state.toString());
    int seconds = state is Workingout ? state.second : 10;
    int minutes = seconds ~/ 60;
    seconds %= 60;
    return '$minutes:${seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }
}
```

This file, is where the problem is, the  `print(state.toString());` only prints `Instance of 'WorkoutInitial'` and its not getting the Workingout state.
Can someone explain to me, why this is happening ?
Thanks.

Edit:-

updated workouttracker code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_responsive_login_ui/features/Profile/profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_responsive_login_ui/features/Routine/routine.dart';
import 'package:flutter_responsive_login_ui/features/WorkoutTracker/bloc/workout_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_responsive_login_ui/features/ExcerciseTrack/excercise_track.dart';

class WorkOutTracker extends StatefulWidget {
  const WorkOutTracker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WorkOutTracker> createState() => _WorkOutTrackerState();
}

class _WorkOutTrackerState extends State<WorkOutTracker> {
  Timer? _timer;

  void updateElapsedTime(Timer timer) {
    context.read<WorkoutBloc>().add(StartWorkout(timer: timer));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => WorkoutBloc(),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: BlocConsumer<WorkoutBloc, WorkoutState>(
          listenWhen: (previous, current) => current is WorkoutActionState,
          buildWhen: (previous, current) => current is! WorkoutActionState,
          listener: (context, state) {},
          builder: (context, state) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          _buildStartWorkoutButton(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  if (state is Workingout) _buildResumeCancelButtons(),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildStartWorkoutButton() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              'Start workout',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: const Text(
              'Start with new routine',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            onPressed: () => _onStartWorkoutButtonPressed(context),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildResumeCancelButtons() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: const Text(
              'Resume workout',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            onPressed: () => _onResumeWorkoutButtonPressed(context),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: const Text(
              'Cancel workout',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            onPressed: () => _onCancelWorkoutButtonPressed(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onStartWorkoutButtonPressed(BuildContext context) {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      (t) async {
        updateElapsedTime(t);
      },
    );
    showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return BlocProvider.value(
          value: context.read<WorkoutBloc>(),
          child: ExcerciseTracker(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _onResumeWorkoutButtonPressed(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return BlocProvider.value(
          value: context.read<WorkoutBloc>(),
          child: ExcerciseTracker(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _onCancelWorkoutButtonPressed() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    context.read<WorkoutBloc>().add(EndWorkout());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, an if I remember right, modalBottomSheet or dialog are creating its own context and you cannot access your bloc there. You have to pass the bloc to the modalBottomSheet(e.g to ExcerciseTracker()) as an argument to ensure that you are using same instance of the bloc, otherwise you are creating a new instans of the bloc with the all initial values.

Maybe it can help you.

UPDATED:

Created a demo example. Look at the modal bottom sheet, it has its own context. Some people name it also "context" and then you are getting en error because this context does not provide your bloc, so just replace it with "_" if you don't use it.

and if you are using classes as states, you have to check for a certain state before you can access it. If you are using one class with copyWith method it goes easer.

Here a demo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

@immutable
abstract class DemoState {}

class DemoInitial extends DemoState {
  final String someValue;
  DemoInitial(this.someValue);
}

@immutable
abstract class DemoEvent {}

class SetNextStateEvent extends DemoEvent {}

class SetPreviousStateEvent extends DemoEvent {}

class DemoBloc extends Bloc<DemoEvent, DemoState> {
  DemoBloc() : super(DemoInitial('Initial value')) {
    on<DemoEvent>((event, emit) {
      // TODO: implement event handler
    });
    on<SetNextStateEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(DemoInitial('Next State'));
    });
    on<SetPreviousStateEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(DemoInitial('Previous State'));
    });
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => DemoBloc(),
        child: BlocBuilder<DemoBloc, DemoState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is DemoInitial) {
              return OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  context.read<DemoBloc>().add(SetNextStateEvent());
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (ITS_OWN_CONTEXT) {
                        return AnotherPageOrWidget(
                            demoBloc: context.read<DemoBloc>());
                      });
                },
                child: Text(state.someValue),
              );
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnotherPageOrWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final DemoBloc demoBloc;

  const AnotherPageOrWidget({required this.demoBloc, super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (demoBloc.state is DemoInitial) {
      return Center(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                demoBloc.add(SetPreviousStateEvent());
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text((demoBloc.state as DemoInitial).someValue)),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child:
                  const Text('Close bottom sheet without changing the state'))
        ],
      ));
    } else {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Error'),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, you are a saviour. Just one quick favour, if you could add some documentation link about it.
It would really make it a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1- In the bloc pattern its not actually correct to create use an instance of bloc this way, you gonna provide your bloc and then use it later using the `read` extension.

2- You are creating totally different instance of your bloc in each class `final WorkoutBloc workoutBloc = WorkoutBloc();` which makes every screen/widget that use it behaves according to its instance that you have created.

so the correct way to use bloc is to use the `BlocProvider<T>` to create the global instance, and use `BlocProvider.value` with the pop-ups (new Screen, modalSheet, dialogs, etc).

The `BlocProvider.value` actually delivers the same instance of the original bloc to your pop-ups.

here is the correct implementation:

```dart
class _WorkOutTrackerState extends State<WorkOutTracker> {
  String elapsedTime = "0s";
  late Timer timer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => WorkoutBloc(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: BlocConsumer<WorkoutBloc, WorkoutState>(
             // bloc: workoutBloc, you don't need that
             listenWhen: (previous, current) => current is WorkoutActionState,
             buildWhen: (previous, current) => current is! WorkoutActionState,
             listener: (context, state) {
               // TODO: implement listener
               print("sdsd");
             },
         ...
  }
}
```

and you can setup your modal sheet popup like that

```dart
  void _onStartWorkoutButtonPressed(BuildContext context) {
    timer = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
        context.read<WorkoutBloc>().add(StartWorkout(timer: timer));
      },
    );
    showWorkoutModalSheet(context);
  }

  void _onResumeWorkoutButtonPressed(BuildContext context) {
    showWorkoutModalSheet(context);
  }

  void showWorkoutModalSheet(BuildContext context) {
    final workoutBloc = context.read<WorkoutBloc>();
    showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return BlocProvider.value(
          value: workoutBloc,
          child: ExcerciseTracker(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

and finally, in your ExcerciseTracker widget you can access your bloc using the read/watch/select extension, `BlocConsumer` or any other bloc Widget without any problem.

```dart
class _ExcerciseTrackerState extends State<ExcerciseTracker> {
 // final WorkoutBloc workoutBloc = WorkoutBloc(); you do not need that

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85,
      child: BlocConsumer<WorkoutBloc, WorkoutState>(
        // bloc: workoutBloc, you do not need that.
        listenWhen: (previous, current) => current is WorkoutActionState,
        buildWhen: (previous, current) => current is! WorkoutActionState,
        listener: (context, state) {
          // TODO: implement listener
          print("sdsd");
        },
      ...
  }
}
```

You can read more about the BLoC pattern from the official docs [here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted).

Comment: ok, i get it, but this is breaking my ` if (state is Workingout) _buildResumeCancelButtons()`, what can be done about that ? Like those button are not visible

Comment: Updated the workout tracker code and getting this now  Error: Could not find the correct Provider<WorkoutBloc> above this WorkOutTracker Widget

Comment: the problem here is that you are passing the context that uses the `context.read<WorkoutBloc>()` from the build widget which is technically does not know about the `BlocProvider` cuz its already in its tree. you have two options:

1- consider converting your helper functions `_buildResumeCancelButtons()` into a separate stateless widget instead, this is also recommended by [flutter team](https://youtu.be/IOyq-eTRhvo).

2- pass the context from another builder widget, but I won't recommend that.

- also you can use the context provided by the BlocConsumer to access your bloc.

Comment: I solved it, by moving the blocProvider to main.dart, idk if its the right approch.